# Why put input selector that is not used in the prompters of the external prompter of createSelector?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

When creating a new selector with `createSelector` that can receive an extra parameter, it is necessary to add the corresponding state part `(items)` next to the external selector input which, in the case shown, would be `categoryName`. Why is this necessary?

Furthermore, when putting `(_, categoryName) => categoryName`, it worked the same way, what is the use of this first parameter?

[print of items slice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pq8n.png)

[print of main component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08OuU.png)

[items, (categoryName) => categoryName],

and it just not work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> ...it is necessary to add the corresponding state part (items) next to
> the external selector input... Why is this necessary?

This is necessary because all selector functions are passed the current Redux store, e.g. state, as the first, *and usually only*, argument.

> Furthermore, when putting `(_, categoryName) => categoryName`, it
> worked the same way, what is the use of this first parameter?

It worked the same way because `"_"` is *just* a valid Javascript identifier, same as `"items"` had you used `(items, categoryName) => categoryName`. Typically we name that first argument `state`, e.g. `(state, categoryName) => categoryName` since that is what it actually is. In this scenario you still need to name the first argument *something* so you can really access the second argument, the "extra" parameter that you want to use in the computed selector function.

> `[items, (categoryName) => categoryName],`
>
> and it just not work

This doesn't work because you have named the passed Redux state `categoryName` and are not consuming the passed extra parameter. In the selector function `categoryName` will just be the entire state value.

Since the state argument is effectively a "throw-away" variable that isn't referenced, there is a naming convention to use `"_"` to indicate that a named variable is intentionally "unused" or is an "internal implementation detail" and isn't meant to be used or referenced.

```js
const items = state => state.items;

createSelector(
  [
    items,                            // <-- selects items state
    (_, categoryName) => categoryName // <-- "selects" categoryName
  ],
  (items, categoryName) => {
    // logic to compute a value using the items state
    // and passed category name value
  },
);
```